# string constant pool using + operator

Tags: java

```
    public class Strings 
    { 
      public static void main(String ads[])
      { 
           String a =    "meow"; 
           String ab = a + "deal"; 
           String abc= "meowdeal"; 
           System.out.println  (ab==abc); 
      } 
    }
```

why output is `false`?
In this program `ab` is created in `string` literal and then `abc` created but why `ab` and `abc` not refer to the same memory in string constant pool ,because before creating `abc` it search in string constant pool for String *meowdeal*.

Comment: thats because it is checking for equality of objects, not its content. try ab.equals(abc) it will show true.

Answer (score 5):

Java only pools strings it knows about at compile time; string constants and constant string expressions.  a is a local variable, so a + "deal" is a string expression that isn't evaluated until runtime (even though you looking at it can see that it should be constant).  The Java compiler doesn't know it's a constant expression, and doesn't put it in the pool.  It performs the string concatenation at runtime, resulting in a different object than any in the pool.

Comment: System.out.println("test" == "te" + "st");------it returns true, why. I got this code from the link provided by @devnull as a comment for this question.

Comment: The constant checker can't "see through" variables of any kind.

Comment: @shin -- "test" == "te" + "st", all the string are constants, so the compiler simplifies "te" + "st" to "test"; it is the same object in the constant pool as "test" written that way.

Comment: @antlersoft ok, thanks for your reply. then java will not pool a string expression which contains any variables or methods in it?

Answer (score 1):

I'll explain what's happening:

```
public class Strings {
           public static void main(String ads[]) {
               String a = "meow"; // new string created
               String ab = a + "deal"; // again a new string created. Reference different.
               String abc = "meowdeal"; // a whole new string.
               System.out.println(ab == abc);// even though the values are same, reference is different. For value equality, use .equals()
           }
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question implies that you expect Java to check the result of every string concatenation to see if there is a matching string in the string constant pool - but this would be grossly inefficient. String concats are always new objects unless all the strings are compile-time constants.

If you really want to compare the strings using `==` you need to intern the constructed string like so:

```
ab=(a+"deal").intern();
```

However this would be for a very specific use case and very uncommon.

Note that this is a different case from when two constants are concatenated; given `"ab"+"cd"` the compiler is *required* to resolve the expression to `"abcd"` and pool the result. The same would be true if one or both of the values are compile-time constants, `static final ...`.